# Org-Mode : adding creation date property upon heading creation

Tags: org-mode

When creating a new section in an Org-Mode document I want to automatically add a `:CREATED: date` property, by example:

```
* Test
:PROPERTIES:
:CREATED:: 2022-06-13 11:05:59
:END:
```

I wrote a solution (see answer) however I am not 100% sure it has no side effect. Maybe a better solution exists ?

Comment: The package `org-expiry.el` provides such a function which one can add to a hook: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13285957/1460448

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I came up with this solution :

```lisp
    (add-hook 'org-insert-heading-hook
    (lambda()
    (save-excursion
              (org-back-to-heading)
              (org-set-property "CREATED" (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d %T")))))
```

---

**UPDATE:**

I read [what-you-need-to-know-about-hooks](https://with-emacs.com/posts/tutorials/what-you-need-to-know-about-hooks/) :

> It’s important to mention that you shouldn’t use anonymous functions
> for your hooks because it becomes hard to tell the purpose of a lambda
> when you inspect the hook at some later point. Another benefit of
> using named functions is that you can easily remove them by passing
> their name to remove-hook.

By consequence, I updated my solution as follows :

```lisp
    (defun set-creation-date-heading-property ()
      (save-excursion
        (org-back-to-heading)
        (org-set-property "CREATED" (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d %T"))))
    
    (defun my-org-mode-date-heading-on ()
      "Turn on heading creation date property"
      (interactive)
      (add-hook 'org-insert-heading-hook #'set-creation-date-heading-property))
    
    (defun my-org-mode-date-heading-off ()
      "Turn off heading creation date property"
      (interactive)
      (remove-hook 'org-insert-heading-hook #'set-creation-date-heading-property))
```

You can use the two functions `my-org-mode-date-heading-on` and `my-org-mode-date-heading-off` to turn on/off automatic creation of the "CREATED" property.

---

**UPDATE of the UPDATE**

Following the interesting comments, here is an example of what can offer a named function (an not a lambda). We can define a toggle function that uses a presence/absence test of the named function.

```lisp
    (defun my-org-mode-date-heading-toggle ()
      "Toggle on/off heading creation date property"
      (interactive)
      (if (memq #'set-creation-date-heading-property org-insert-heading-hook)
          (progn
           (my-org-mode-date-heading-off)
           (message "off - heading creation date"))
        (progn
          (my-org-mode-date-heading-on)
          (message "on - heading creation date"))))
```

Comment: You might want to consider bracketing the time string, to make it an inactive time stamp: `(format-time-string "[%Y-%m-%d %T]")`

Comment: Also note that the `save-excursion` and `org-back-to-heading` are superfluous; `org-set-property` by itself handles that.

Comment: I currently add a `CREATED` property as part of my org-capture templates, but this approach seems neater. However, I've noticed that this hook function does not run if the heading is being inserted by `org-capture`. Why is that, and what would be needed to change it so that `set-creation-date-heading-property` runs even during capture?

Comment: @tkp You might want to look into [template expansion](https://orgmode.org/manual/Template-expansion.html) and sexp-evaluation in the form of `%(EXP)` in particular.

Comment: Based on Picaud's answer, and @PhilHudson and @DanDrake's comments, and an OrgMode-provided function, this can be condensed further into `(add-hook 'org-insert-heading-hook (lambda () (org-set-property "CREATED" (format-time-string (org-time-stamp-format t t)))))`. Note that this does not honour the reasonable point made in Picaud's updated answer.